# Select one row without duplicate entries keyword based

Tags: php, mysql, sql

My `info` table has the following columns:

```
Id | Name | City | date | status
```

I want to select all names from `info`, and am using the following query:

```
$query = mysql_query("SELECT name FROM info WHERE status = 1 ORDER BY id") 
         or die(mysql_error());

while ($raw = mysql_fetch_array($query)) 
{
  $name = $raw["name"];
  echo ''.$name.'<br>';
}
```

name columns content example :

```
alex
alex1
alex2
michel22
michel33
michel44
```

Well, the result is that it returns all the entries. I want to echo all the entries without duplicates but only content specfied keyword

Saying: under raw `name` we have inserted the name "alex and michel" 10 times and in different format.

I want to echo only :

```
alex
michel
```

one time its possibile ?

Comment: **WARNING**: If you're just learning PHP, please, do not learn the obsolete [`mysql_query`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-query.php) interface. It's awful and has been removed in PHP 7. A replacement like [PDO is not hard to learn](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/php/why-you-should-be-using-phps-pdo-for-database-access/) and a guide like [PHP The Right Way](http://www.phptherightway.com/) helps explain best practices. Make **sure** your user parameters are [properly escaped](http://bobby-tables.com/php) or you will end up with severe [SQL injection bugs](http://bobby-tables.com/).

Comment: By what logic do you want your code to identify that `['alex', 'alex1', 'alex2']` should all be treated as equivalent?  Based on your sample data you could just strip out all the numerals and keep only the alphabetic characters?  Would that be sufficient?  *(If you don't know how to do it manually, then you'll never get a computer to automate it.)*

Answer (score 0):

first of all use mysqli or pdo to interface your database. mysql is deprecated.

```
$mysqli = new mysqli($dbhost, $dbuser, $dbpass, $dbname);
$result = mysqli_query($mysqli,"SELECT name FROM info WHERE status = 1 ORDER BY id") or die(mysqli_error($mysqli));

$uniqueNames = array();
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
    $nameWithoutNumbers = preg_replace('/[0-9]+/', '', $row["name"]); //removes the numbers and leave only names
    $uniqueNames[$nameWithoutNumbers] = 1; //just a filtering hack, if key exits value is replaced otherwise a new key is created
}
foreach($uniqueNames as $name => $one)
    echo $name; //remember you were saving your names as keys pointing to 1s
```